# DFS/BFS implementation of Cormen's pseudo code

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

This is DFS/BFS C++ code for Cormen pseudo code. Please comment on this.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "list"

enum color{
    WHITE,
    GREY,
    BLACK
};

struct edge{
    int destination_vertex;
    edge(int ver){
        destination_vertex = ver;
    }
};

struct vertex{
    int id;
    color visited;
    std::list<edge>  list;
    vertex(int _id){
        id = _id;
    }
};


class graph
{
private:
    std::vector<vertex> vertexes;
    void dfs_visits(vertex& source);
    int next;
public:
    graph(void){
        next = 0;
    }
    ~graph(void){}
    void dfs();
    void bfs();
};



void graph::dfs(void)
{
    for(std::vector<vertex>::iterator iter =vertexes.begin();iter < vertexes.end();iter++ ){
        iter->visited = WHITE;  
    }   

    for(std::vector<vertex>::iterator iter =vertexes.begin();iter < vertexes.end();iter++ ){
        if(iter->visited == WHITE){
            dfs_visits(*iter);
        }
    }
}


void graph::dfs_visits(vertex& source){
    source.visited = GREY;
    for(std::list<edge>::iterator iter = source.list.begin();iter != source.list.end();iter++){
        if(vertexes[iter->destination_vertex].visited == WHITE){
            dfs_visits(vertexes[iter->destination_vertex]);
        }
    }
    source.visited = BLACK;
    std::cout<< source.id <<std::endl;
}

void graph::bfs(){

    for(std::vector<vertex>::iterator iter=vertexes.begin();iter != vertexes.end();iter++){
        iter->visited = WHITE;
    }

    std::queue<vertex*> bsf_q;

    bsf_q.push(&vertexes[0]);

    while(!bsf_q.empty()){
        vertex * v = bsf_q.front();
        bsf_q.pop();

        for(std::list<edge>::iterator iter = v->list.begin() ;iter != v->list.end();iter++ ){
            if(vertexes[iter->destination_vertex].visited == WHITE){
                vertexes[iter->destination_vertex].visited = GREY;
                bsf_q.push(& vertexes[iter->destination_vertex]);
            }
        }

        v->visited = BLACK;
        std::cout << v->id <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Preliminaries

It's conventional to include system headers [with brackets instead of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162067/819272) and [prefer `std::vector` over `std::list`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471461/819272) unless proven wrong by a benchmark (note that the use of the word "list" in CLRS is not used in the same sense as `std::list`).

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
```

### Data structures

[Separate your algorithms and data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11948413/819272) and use a common naming convention where types have capitalized initial letters

```
enum { 
    INFINITY = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() 
};

enum Color {
    WHITE,
    GREY,
    BLACK
};

struct Vertex {
    int id;

    // BFS properties
    Color color;
    int discovery;
    Vertex* parent;

    // DFS properties
    int finish;
};

// adjacenty list representation (Figure 22.1 (b) of CLRS 3rd ed.)
struct Graph {
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector< std::vector<Vertex*> > adjacent;
};
```

Several things can be said about my choice of data structures. *For the purpose of illustrating BFS and DFS* I wouldn't make them full-fledged classes with data hiding. You also need to set up some scaffolding code to initialize a `Graph` object, and make sure that the `Vertex*` inside `adjacent` are actually only pointing to `Vertex` objects inside `vertices` of the same `Graph` object (so that in fact `adjacent` only holds non-owning pointers). Real-world code would encapsulate the enforcement of such invariants inside the constructor and modifying member functions. For brevity this is not being show.

I also would remove the `Edge` class because it is implicitly represented as an `Vertex*` in the adjacency list graph representation. Finally, because the `id` in `Vertex` is an `int`, you get away with using a `std::vector` as a container. For `std::string` vertex labels, one would need to use a `std::map<std::string, std::vector<Vertex*>>` for the `adjacent` data inside `Graph`.

Note that the properties of BFS and DFS are put inside `Vertex`. This is to accomodate the style of notation of CLRS. They write on p592 that you can put that information in separate data structures as well (e.g. a `std::map<Vertex*, SearchProperties>`). Boost.Graph (the closest thing in C++ to a standardized graph implementation) uses such [property maps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) to achieve the same effect more elegantly.

### Breadth-first search

Document your algorithms pre- and post-conditions, as well as the runtime complexity as a function of the input size (look it up in CLRS!). I would give the function `breadth_first_search` the same signature as in CLRS, except that they are not very careful about whether they pass by value, reference or pointer.

```
#include <queue>

// pre-condition: graph of vertices with unitialized BFS properties
void breadth_first_search(Graph& g, Vertex* s)
{       
    for (auto& v: g.vertices)
        if (v.id == s->id) continue;
        v.color = WHITE;
        v.discovery = INFINITY;
        v.parent = nullptr;
    }
    s->color = GRAY;
    s->discovery = 0;
    s->parent = nullptr;    
    std::queue<Vertex*> q;
    q.push(s);    
    while (!q.empty()) {
        auto u = q.front();
        q.pop();    
        for (auto v: G.adjacent[u->id])) {
            if (v->color == WHITE) {
                v->color = GRAY;
                v->discovery = u->discovery + 1;
                v->parent = u;
                q.push(v);
            }
        }
        u->color = BLACK;
    }
}
// post-condition: graph with initialized vertex color and discovery times
```

Notice that I would strongly recommend to use the C++11 features [`auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8542873/819272) type deduction and [ranged for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6963894/819272). These enormously improve the readability of your code: the code above is in almost exactly the same notation as the listing of BFS(G,s) on p595 of CLRS (except that I use `color`, `discovery` and `parent` instead of the terser `c`, `d` and `pi`.

Except for debugging purposes, I would eliminate the `std::cout` calls from the BFS algorithm. Because the algorithm also keeps track of the `parent` information, you can completely retrace the algorithms steps after it finishes, should you want to, and print whatever information necessary.

### Depth-first search

For the depth-first search, I again would follow the CLRS conventions as much as possible:

```
void depth_first_search(Graph& g)
{
    for (auto& u: g.vertices) {
        u.color = WHITE;
        u.parent = nullptr;
    }

    for (auto& u: g.vertices) {
        if (u.color == WHITE)
            depth_first_search_visit(g, &u, 1)
    }
}

void depth_first_search_visit(Graph& g, Vertex* u, int time)
{
    u->color = GRAY;
    u->discovery = time;
    for (auto v: g.adjacent[u->id]) {
        if (v->color == WHITE) {
            v->parent = u;
            depth_first_search_visit(G, u, time + 1)
        }
    }
    u->color = BLACK;
    u->finish = time + 1;    
}
```

Note that I would pass the `time` variable by value along the recursive calls to `depth_first_search_visit`, which makes it slightly clearer to reason about the algorithm (and also avoids a few explicit increments here and there). Again note that the code above is in almost exactly the same notation as the listing of DFS(G) on p604 of CLRS.

**Extra:** note that BFS is written as a single function with an init phase + infinite loop over a `std::queue`, and DFS as an init function + a recursive fuction. It is a nice exercise to rewrite DFS as a single function with an init phase + infinite loop over a `std::stack` (instead of the implicit stack used by the recursion).

### Further reading

If you want to know how the pros are doing it: familiarize yourself with [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: @bapusethi glad to have been of help!